# How to calculate a perspective transform matrix in 3D with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computational-geometry, perspectivecamera

I have two sets of 2D points: A and B. I can calculate a 3x3 perspective transform matrix between these sets with `getPerspectiveTransform()`. Let's place these sets (planes) in 3D coordinate system (each point acquires a Z-coordinate now) to get two 3D sets: A' and B'. There is no equivalent of `getPerspectiveTransform()` for this 3D case. What is the way to calculate a 4x4 perspective transform matrix between A' and B'? It doesn't have to be OpenCV, if there are other convenient libraries with that functionality.

**NOTE**

The application is a projector calibration, therefore camera models are not directly applicable. I have an accurate 2D homography between projector image source and projected image. I have much less accurate measurement of world position and orientation of the projector. I need to extend the transform to objects relatively close to the projected image plane. I know I can do it by calculating ray intersection with projected image plane, but I'm looking for a more compact solution in the form of a transform matrix.

**NOTE'**

I'm insisting on the transformation being a projection, because that's the real-world geometry I'm modelling. B' points lie on the plane in 3D, specifically on the image forming rectangle inside the projector. A' points are projections of B' onto a 3D surface. It may be planar, requiring additional parameters or points outside the plane for the transformation to be unique .

Comment: `getPerspectiveTransform` uses four point pairs. `findHomography` works for multiple point pairs. -- you probably want something like "Iterative Closest Point" (ICP), which is a method for aligning point clouds, which is **not** a perspective transform because you don't need, and nor should you require, a perspective transformation for this

Comment: Rigid transformation. Maybe avsilable in Open3D library.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Neither `getPerspectiveTransform` nor `findHomography` accepts 3D points. I need a transformation in 3D.

Comment: I didn't say that they would. I said getPerspectiveTransform is a special case of findHomography for *four* point pairs (2D). read on. I mentioned an algorithm that will help you. you still haven't clarified why you think you need a *perspective* transformation. it looks like you don't need one, and in fact shouldn't use one.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz See the note I just added.

Comment: ah, so you need to calibrate ("extrinsics") the position of the projector and the camera to each other. aruco markers are always a good idea for that. I think you can calibrate the projector by projecting one marker on different planes, and measuring that from the camera.

Comment: I think epipolar geometry might be what you are looking for. Have a look at fundamental matrix and Zisserman's book.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a rigid transform between two sets of 3D points. I think the closest function in opencv for this is: [cv::estimateAffine3D](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gac12d1f05b3bb951288e7250713ce98f0).

Comment: @vasiliykarasev Not really. Perspective transform can't be expressed as a composition of rotation, translation and scaling, which is what `estimateAffine3D` computes.

Comment: How can a transformation from one 3D point set to another 3D point set be "perspective"? If you can solve your problem with ray-to-3d-plane intersection, you can just solve it with a 2D perspective homography, as far as I understand.

Comment: you probably notice that multiple people are confused by your question. please take that as a prompt for you to clarify the question, add illustrations/pictures, whatever's necessary to flesh it out.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I added more explanation. Hopefully it is more clear now.